# I have an issue with printing lines one by one with for loop

Tags: powershell

```
$data = Get-Content "C:\export\List_Of_Modules.txt"

$cnt=$data.count

$i=0

for($i=0;$i -gt $cnt ;$i++)

{
Write-Host $data[$i]

write-host $i

}
```

When I run the above code I'm getting only a blank result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop condition should be `-lt` instead of `-gt`:

```
for($i=0;$i -lt $cnt ;$i++)
{
    Write-Host $data[$i]
}
```

Also worth mentioning that you can use the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet to *iterate* over each line:

```
Get-Content "C:\export\List_Of_Modules.txt" | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host $_
}
```

Comment: Excellent,
Thank you so much it worked and i'm able to get the expect result now :)